# ImageCreateFromString and getimagesize in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing

Currently if a user POST/uploads a photo to my PHP script I start out with some code like this

```
getimagesize($_FILES['picture1']['tmp_name']);
```

I then do a LOT more stuff to it but I am trying to also be able to get a photo from a URL and process it with my other existing code if I can.  SO I am wanting to know, I f I use something like this

```
$image = ImageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($url));
```

Would I be able to then run  getimagesize() on my $image variable?

---

---

**UPDATE**

I just tried this...

```
$url = 'http://a0.twimg.com/a/1262802780/images/twitter_logo_header.png';
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($url));
$imageinfo = getimagesize($image);
print_r($imageinfo);
```

But it didnt work, gave this.

```
Warning: getimagesize(Resource id #4) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

Any idea how I can do this or something similar to get the result I am after?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you follow this approach:

```
// if you need the image type
$type = exif_imagetype($url);

// if you need the image mime type
$type = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($url));

// if you need the image extension associated with the mime type
$type = image_type_to_extension(exif_imagetype($url));

// if you don't care about the image type ignore all the above code
$image = ImageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($url));

echo ImageSX($image); // width
echo ImageSY($image); // height
```

Using `exif_imagetype()` is a lot faster than `getimagesize()`, the same goes for `ImageSX()` / `ImageSY()`, plus they don't return arrays **and** can also return the correct image dimension after the image has been resized or cropped for instance.

Also, using `getimagesize()` on URLs isn't good because it'll consume much more bandwidth than the alternative `exif_imagetype()`, from the [PHP Manual](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php):

> When a correct signature is found, the
>   appropriate constant value will be
>   returned otherwise the return value is
>   FALSE. The return value is the same
>   value that `getimagesize()` returns in
>   index 2 but `exif_imagetype()` is much
>   faster.

That's because `exif_imagetype()` will only read the first few bytes of data.

Comment: I somehow missed `imagesx()` and `imagesy()` in the manual. Thanks for that! +1

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got an image resource, you'd get the size using the [imagesx](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php) and imagesy functions.

Comment: the asker probably want other information about the image as to only height and width. such as image type, mime type and so on.

Answer (score 0):

getimagesize can be used with HTTP.

> *Filename* - It can reference a local file or (configuration permitting) **a remote file using one of the supported streams**.

Thus

```
$info = getimagesize($url);
$image = ImageCreateFromString(file_get_contents($url));
```

should be fine.

Comment: Great that works, I was trying to getimagesize from the value of $image, after it already grabs the image instead of hitting the URL twice but if that is the way it need to be done then thats fine

Comment: Doesn't that download the file twice?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I ran into a similar issue and it turned out the firewall controlled by my host was blocking outgoing http connection from my server.

They changed the firewall settings. My code then worked.

BTW: I thought this might have been an issue when I tried file_get_contents() on a number of urls, none of which worked!