# PHP using getimagesize() on a file (not a file name)

Tags: php, mime-types, getimagesize

I am making an attachments system for my website.  In a form-based upload method, you can get the image size using:

```
$SizeResult = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

But using a Drag&Drop upload system via HTML5's File API, the files are uploaded not by form post, but by black magic & wizardry.

```
$File = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

In this case $File is not a *name*, but the actual binary contents of the file.

How can I get the size of said $File, when [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) only seems to accept file *names*?  Internally, **getimagesize** wants to open the file from disk itself.  It doesn't want to accept $File.

Anyone know how I can get around this issue?  I'm hoping to avoid saving the file to disk.

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024789/imagecreatefromstring-and-getimagesize-in-php. Basically: use imagesx and imagesy on an image resource.

Comment: Eduardo, thanks for replying, that is a useful link.  I followed Alix Axel's post and it works... sorta.  **getimagesize()** and **exif_imagetype()** do work if you pass them the URL directly.  So for example, this works: `$SizeResult = getimagesize('php://input');` But then, my problem is... in order to get the actual file, I'd have to run `$File = file_get_contents('php://input');` ... essentially download the file twice (right?)  That doesn't seem efficient :(

Comment: I think you should be fine with a single read. I'll post an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I meant, please try it:

```
$File = file_get_contents('php://input');
$image = ImageCreateFromString($File);
echo ImageSX($image); // width
echo ImageSY($image); // height
```

Comment: Eduardo, I will edit my post to clarify, but I'm not trying to get the size (in bytes) of the file.  I'm trying to get the size (in width and height -- as in pixels) of the file (assuming it's an image).  [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) is a function in PHP that returns this info, as well as MIME type and other useful info.  But you are correct that strlen() would certainly get the size (in bytes)

Comment: Argh, my mistake! I'm sleepier than I thought it seems : ) Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry about the delay.  Yes, this did work, although I'm a bit sad because ImageCreateFromString uses GD and can take a lot of memory.  Nevertheless it works so I appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I made a solution that I think is best.  I must confess that the primary reason for using the **getimagesize()** function was to get the MIME type of the file (to ensure it is an image).  Obtaining the size is an added bonus, but I could have just as easily framed the question around the **exif_imagetype()** function.  The problem would have been the same, because both functions only accept a file *name*; not file contents.

So what I did was basically look in the PHP sourcecode and see how **exif_imagetype()** read MIME information.  It turns out it only reads the first 12 bytes of the file.  I replicated its functionality like so:

```
function GetConstMimeArray()
{
    // MIME type markers (taken from PHP sourcecode consts in \ext\standard\image.c starting at line 39).
    return array
    (
        'gif' => array(ord('G'), ord('I'), ord('F')),
        'psd' => array(ord('8'), ord('B'), ord('P'), ord('S')),
        'bmp' => array(ord('B'), ord('M')),
        'swf' => array(ord('F'), ord('W'), ord('S')),
        'swc' => array(ord('C'), ord('W'), ord('S')),
        'jpg' => array(0xff, 0xd8, 0xff),
        'png' => array(0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x1a, 0x0a),
        'tif_ii' => array(ord('I'), ord('I'), 0x2a, 0x00),
        'tif_mm' => array(ord('M'), ord('M'), 0x00, 0x2a),
        'jpc' => array(0xff, 0x4f, 0xff),
        'jp2' => array(0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x6a, 0x50, 0x20, 0x20, 0x0d, 0x0a, 0x87, 0x0a),
        'iff' => array(ord('F'), ord('O'), ord('R'), ord('M')),
        'ico' => array(0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00)
    );
}
```

And

```
// Get an array of known MIME headers.
$MimeTypeConsts = GetConstMimeArray();

// Get first 12 bytes of file from stream to do a MIME check.
$File = file_get_contents('php://input', null, null, 0, 12);
if(strlen($File) < 12)
    return;

// Scan first 12 bytes of file for known MIME headers.
$MatchedMime = '';
foreach($MimeTypeConsts as $Type => $Bytes)
{
    $NumMatching = 0;
    $NumBytes = count($Bytes);
    for($i = 0; $i < $NumBytes; $i++)
    {
        if(ord($File[$i]) == $Bytes[$i])
            $NumMatching++;
        else
            break;
    }
    if($NumMatching == $NumBytes)
    {
        $MatchedMime = $Type;
        break;
    }
}

// Check if the file does NOT have one of the known MIME types.
if(strlen($MatchedMime) <= 0)
    return;

// If we fix up TIF_TT and TIF_MM, you can use $MatchedMime in lieu
// of the extension on the file name.
if($MatchedMime == 'tif_ii' || $MatchedMime == 'tif_mm')
    $MatchedMime = 'tif';

// What's the max size allowed to upload?
$MaxSize = min(ReturnBytes(ini_get('post_max_size')), MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE);

// Get full file.
$File = file_get_contents('php://input', null, null, 0, $MaxSize + 8);

// Get file size.
$Size = strlen($File);
if($Size > $MaxSize)
    return;

// Get hash of the file contents.
$Hash = hash('SHA1', $File, true);

file_put_contents(UPLOADS_DIR.'/'.bin2hex($Hash).'.'.$MatchedMime, $File);
```

The file will now be saved in UPLOADS_DIR using the hash as it's name and the MIME type as its extension.  (Whatever extension was originally on the file name is ignored and not used.)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<?php
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");
echo "<img src=\"img/flag.jpg\" $attr alt=\"getimagesize() example\" />";
?>
```